# FETCH the latest partition from HIVE table

Tags: sql, hive, qliksense, hive-query

Hi I am very much new to this.
I have three columns YEAR, MONTH,DAY in INTEGER format.

I want to load the script and combine YEAR,MONTH,DAY as single column and fetch the maximum.

I tried like,

```
Load year,month,date from HIVE.`abc`.`abc1';
SELECT max(cast(year as String) || '_' || cast(month as string) || '_' || cast(day as string)) as result FROM HIVE.`abc`.`abc1';
```

By doing this I will get the result as 2020_5_21. But I should use the separator and find the max of the date.

> The following error occurred: Connector reply error: SQL##f -
> SqlState: S1000, ErrorCode: 35, ErrorMsg: [Cloudera][Hardy] (35) Error
> from server: error code: '1' error message: 'Error while compiling
> statement: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from
> org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezTask'.

I want to use the result in WHERE clause. But I don't know the statement.
SQL select * from HIVE.`abc`.`abc1' where ---- ;

Please help.

Comment: Check job tracker and find exception message in failed container log. Console exception message is not informative

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If month and day are stored as integers, you need to use lpad() to add zero if it is single digit month or day. For example month `5` should become `05`.  Without this max may work incorrectly. Also use dash as a separator to have date in compatible format.

```
max(concat(year,'-',lpad(month, 2,0),'-',lpad(day, 2,0)))
```

And to use it in the WHERE use `WHERE date in (select max ...)`:

```
SELECT * from your_table
WHERE concat(year,'-',lpad(month, 2,0),'-',lpad(day, 2,0)) in (select max(concat(year,'-',lpad(month, 2,0),'-',lpad(day, 2,0))) from your_table)
```

Also you may need to quote names like year, month, day in backticks everywhere in sql:

```
max(concat(`year`,'-',lpad(`month`, 2,0),'-',lpad(`day`, 2,0)))
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232415/discussion-on-answer-by-leftjoin-fetch-the-latest-partition-from-hive-table).

Comment: @leftjoin Finally, the query worked after setting the queue name. Thanks.

Comment: @leftjoin Now I have duplicates in my table.The same row is repeated twice (uppercase and lowercase for empname field) Any help to change the query by having distinct values.

Comment: @jaichu Please avoid asking questions in the comments. Create one more question with data example and problem description please and someone will help. Duplicates problem is not related your initial question.